# Redirect after Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc project, what I want to do is this:

I am sending an ajax request from my JS script. After processing it I want to redirect to a page with a model.

Now I tried sending a form as the ajax response and submit it like so:

```
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", "url..");
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='result' value='{0}'>", val1);
.....
```

And on the JS:

```
success: function (result) {
            var form = $(result);
            $(form).submit();
        }
```

But this way i need to specify each post param, I want to send the entire model object.
How can I do that?

**Edit**
Full steps:

1.Using an MVC APP.

2.I submit button in my view which redirects the user to my JS code.

3.Js code sends an Ajax request to a MVC page called 'Transaction'.

4.C# code doing some actions and now I need to redirect the usr to a page named EOF with **ALOT** of post params, thats why I want to pass it as a ViewModel.

Comment: I'm not clear what your asking

Comment: not able to understand question..plz put some more explanation what do want actually???

Comment: 1.I Sent an ajax from my Js to my mvc page . 2. I want to redirect to another page with a mvc ViewModel - Thats all! which part is not clear?

Comment: you cannot redirect to other page with model values...you can go to other page with window.location.href="// path of page //"...but without model values...

Comment: @Exception, Of course you can - just create the relevant query string

Comment: Is your second controller method (that you are going to redirect) `post` one or `get` one ?

Comment: _"which part is not clear?"_. Sorry, but none of it based on your code and the terminology your using. Please try and give a clearer step by step explanation of what your trying to do.

Comment: Updated it again, I hope its clearer now. Please take a look. @Saranga - post params.

Comment: @user3770158...just see updated answer i think this is what you want...

Comment: @Exception It might work, I will try it

Comment: @user3770158...-3 i don't know what is happening???

Comment: Why post using ajax, and not just use the default submit, then redirect in the post action method?

Comment: Its possible, but that's not the question :]

Comment: try returning JavaScriptResult: ``return JavaScript("<script>alert(\"some message\")</script>");``

Answer (score 2):

As you are using ajax, you could return the URL from your action and have it redirected in javascript:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Transaction()
{
    // Do stuff
    return Json(new { success = true, redirecturl = Url.Action("RedirectedAction") });
}
```

Then add something like this to your success handler in javascript:

**Javascript (within your success handler)**

```
success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == true)
            {
               window.location = result.redirecturl;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public ActionResult YourMethod(string param)
{
   //what ever you want to do with reference no
    return View("EOF");
   // or, if you want to supply a model to EOF:
   // return View("EOF", myModel);
}
```